# angular.forEach Resolving Nested Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have to make sequential AJAX calls after retrieving a collection of data. I am having issues resolving the nested promises.

Basically, I need to extend each object returned in my first collection with a property of `ActionItems` and set it's value with a promise then resolve each promise in the collection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Factory**

```
$http.get(urlBase + 'Project?$expand=Plant,CreatedBy,ModifiedBy,Plant/Contacts').then(function(success){
        var contents = {};
        contents = success.data.d.results;

        return contents;
    })
    .then(function(contents){ 
        var contentPromises = [];
        angular.forEach(contents, function(content) {
            contentPromises.push(
                $http.get(urlBase + "ActionItems?$filter=ProjectId eq " + content.Id ).then(function(success){
                    content['ActionItems'] = success.data.d.results;                         
                })
            );
        });
        return $q.all(contentPromises).then(function() {
            return contents;
        });
    });
```

**Current Output is undefined**

Comment: And what isn't working with your code?

Comment: It returns undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well turns out this method works, but the key to getting your data back is returning it...

```
//Forgot the return below...
return $http.get(urlBase + 'Project?$expand=Plant,CreatedBy,ModifiedBy,Plant/Contacts').then(function(success){
    var contents = {};
    contents = success.data.d.results;

    return contents;
})
.then(function(contents){ 
    var contentPromises = [];
    angular.forEach(contents, function(content) {
        contentPromises.push(
            $http.get(urlBase + "ActionItems?$filter=ProjectId eq " + content.Id ).then(function(success){
                content['ActionItems'] = success.data.d.results;                         
            })
        );
    });
    return $q.all(contentPromises).then(function() {
        return contents;
    });
});
```

Thanks for all who helped.

Comment: Consider using `.map` on contents.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lies within the `$http.get(...).then()` part.

[The documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api) for `.then` is telling us that "This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback".
So the promise returned by `.then` is different than the one returned by `$http.get`. And you are responsible of resolving or rejecting it (by returning)! The promise returned by `.then` is the one pushed to `contentPromises`.

Thus you need something like this:

```
angular.forEach(contents, function(content) {
    contentPromises.push(
        $http.get(urlBase + "ActionItems?$filter=ProjectId eq " + content.Id ).then(function(success){
            content['ActionItems'] = success.data.d.results;
            return success;                         
        })
    );
});
```

You'd do well to implement the `errorCallback` too.